# TEMPLATEPATH without the theme name? No THEMEPATH constant?

Tags: plugin-development

Is there a way to get a path to the themes directory without the current theme in the path?

ie, in a standard WP install, I would want a reference to:

> C:\xampplite\htdocs\sitename/wp-content/themes/

But the TEMPLATEPATH constant returns...

> C:\xampplite\htdocs\sitename/wp-content/themes/currentActiveTheme

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
dirname( STYLESHEETPATH );
```

That will return the theme directory.

**Never** assume `/wp-content/` below ABSPATH. I’m using often a different directory and domain for `wp-content` to enable cookieless requests to theme files. Bad plugins and themes break terribly in such cases.

#### Addendum

Or use `get_theme_root()` for the file path and `get_theme_root_uri()` for the URI. Both are defined in `wp-includes/theme.php`.

Comment: + 1 Thanks. This works too. Would there be any benefit to using this vs imHavoc's answer?

Comment: @Scott B There should be no difference. `STYLESHEETPATH` is defined in `wp-includes/default-constants.php` calling `get_stylesheet_directory()` which is asking `get_theme_root()`.

Comment: actually, after further review, yours is the more appropriate answer for my question. it returns a *file* path, not a URL path as get_theme_root_uri() does (c:\ as opposed to http://) and since I'm moving files, that's what I needed in this case.

Comment: @Scott B I added the two functions for for the path and the URI to complete the answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is no THEMEPATH constant, but you can use the `get_theme_root_uri()` function to retrieve the path to the themes folder.

Comment: This looks like the best option. Testing it now.

Comment: This works perfectly, however, in this case, I'm looking for a file path, not a URL path. I'm moving files on the server from a plugin folder to the themes folder. Your answer works fine though, depending on the context of the question.

Answer (score 2):

WP_CONTENT_DIR and WP_CONTENT_URL as well as content_url() get you most of the way there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the constant `ABSPATH` and just append to it `wp-content/themes/` so:

```
ABSPATH . "wp-content/themes/"
```

Comment: Can the user specify any directory other than wp-content/themes to store their themes?

Comment: @Scott: It is possible but very hard to acomplish and not very likly that anyone has.

Comment: Two lines in wp-config.php aren’t that hard. ;) Just define WP_CONTENT_DIR and WP_CONTENT_URL.

Comment: @toscho: thanks, you learn new stuff every day, i was just reading about it at http://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories